# CLK320 ac problem

Tags: ac, mercedes-benz

my 1999 CLK320 has a problem with the ac compressor. Car runs well but the AC cuts out after being on for about 5 to 10 minutes. if the ac is then turned off for a few minutes it will come on again but only for a short while. All other temps checked and appear to be normal. No overheating. No error codes. when the AC is running it is blowing cold-HELP please

Answer (score 1):

The compressor has it's own cut off for internal temperature. When it's starting to go bad, it overheats itself from friction(bearing?). If you replace it before it cooks your refrigerant...you might save the other components that seem to still help blow COLD air. Consider replacing it pronto, cheers!